# jQuery script execution order in html injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

Consider the following JS code:

```
var html = '<script>$("body").append("a");</script>'
         + '<script src="script.js"></script>'
         + '<script>$("body").append("c");</script>';

$("body").append(html);
```

And assume that script.js contains the following:

```
$("body").append("b");
```

It seems that, indeed, "a", "b" and "c" are appended to body (**in this order**). And, obviously, "c" is appended to body only after `script.js` has finished loading (so, for example, if it takes 5 seconds for `script.js` to finish loading "c" will be appended to body only after 5 seconds).

My question is the following: can we rely on this behavior in jQuery? Is it deterministic or we may encounter unpredictable situations?

This would be useful in terms of dynamically loading scripts that make use of .js files that were not loaded yet. You can assume that script.js actually contains `function f(){}` and the third line would have been `<script>f()</script>`. If you will always get the same order for the scripts loading/execution then there will be no issues, otherwise you may experience `f is not defined` exception (if the  tag is executed before loading the script.js file).

Comment: You should avoid injecting strings that contain `<script>` elements that contain JavaScript, as that is not a sound architectural approach to script management. jQuery has a [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method that is meant explicitly for loading scripts, and makes use of promises so that you can easily chain script inclusions: `$.getScript('foo.js').done(function () {$.getScript('bar.js')});`

Comment: An even better way to manage script dependencies is to rely on a tool such as [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a jQuery specific behavior as much as it is a browser behavior.  When loading scripts that are pre-defined in the document, they are loaded in order or appearance.  The same is not true when you dynamically append the script tag to the document.

If you loaded the javascript files like you show, it will start to download the the external file when the source of the element is set by the DOM.

### Example:

#### Script in head of Html file

```
$(function() {
    var html = '<script>$("body").append("a");<\/script>' +
               '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>' +
               '<script>$("#my-dialog").dialog();<\/script>';

    $("body").append(html);
}
```

#### Body element of Html file

```
<div id="my-dialog">
    Some content here
</div>
```

The above code wouldn't execute as you expect. `a` would be appended to the body and then `jQuery.ui` to be loaded and finally a `dialog` would appear, but in fact the third script would fail because jQueryUI hasn't finished downloading and has yet to be parsed.  Now if you typed `$("#my-dialog").dialog();` into the console, there wouldn't be any issues since the file is downloaded and parsed at that point.

This is one of the main reasons module loaders are popular.  You just tell it what it requires and it will take care of loading them for you in the needed order.

You can read more about the W3C spec for scripts [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script).

Comment: I'm aware of the module loaders but I'm also interested in being able to load scripts using <script> tags. Also, the script in your example will work just fine if jQuery UI will be loaded from the local server instead of ajax.googleapis.com (jQuery will load the script, wait for this to load and then run the 3rd instruction). Also my question is related to the way jQuery processes the scripts when injecting HTML (the browser by itself will not parse any scripts when injecting).

Comment: @Razvan I will say that excluding third-party hosted libraries, I couldn't get it to load out of order using "synchronous" methods.  I wouldn't say that this would occur all the time though.  It did fail with `timeout` though.  Just with that right there I would strongly discourage the use of this "pattern" as most situations where callbacks are used could cause it to fail if you aren't careful.